# How do you get your objects local transformations back after applying them?

Tags: transform-orientation

Say I have a cube, and I rotate it randomly. I set the transform orientation from Gloabl to Local, and I move on the Z axis. The cube won't move up, it will move in whatever Z axis it has instead.

Now, say I go to Object, and Apply All Transforms; now when I move on the Z axis, it will move up and down.

Is there anyway to get the local transformation back after applying them?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to recover those applied transform without undoing. One solution could be copying the transforms to an empty and then copy them back again from the empty when you finish.